# What is the maximum signature ability level on Marvel Contest of the Champions?

Tags: marvel-contest-champions

When a player gets a duplicate of a champion he unlocks the signature ability. Each duplicate will increase the level of that ability. I have a Punisher with signature ability level 8.

How many duplicates of a champion can one get? What is the maximum signature ability level on Marvel Contest of the Champions?

I am not concerned by hacks and stuff... My question concerns the official game.

Comment: I don't know the actual limit, but it is at least 99.

Comment: @winterblood Thx for your comment. Do you know that because you have a champion with a signature ability level 99? Or because you read somewhere? If you don't mind my asking :)

Comment: Level 99 Iron Man (not mine) as seen in [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4nMzNMhtSA)

Comment: @winterblood Yeah, I've watched this video before. I've also seen [this post on gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/822336-marvel-contest-of-champions/71397594?page=1) where someone states that current max level is 99, but without any evidence to support it... thx man!

Comment: @winterblood Yes, you were right, it is currently level 99, you can answer the question so we can close it.

Comment: [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ContestOfChampions/comments/3mi0w8/99_duped_deadpool/) is a reddit post showing a recently added deadpool X. He got at least 5 duplicates. Each one gives +20 lvls on signature ability. 99 is the maximum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The maximum level for a Signature Ability is currently 99.

- Tier 1 champions have no signature ability.
- Getting a Tier 2 duplicate will upgrade a Signature Ability by 1 level. Exceptions: dupping Unstoppable Colossus and Punisher will increase their signature ability by 2 levels. I guess it is because they can only be obtained by alliance crystal and versus crystal respectively.
- Getting a Tier 3 duplicate will upgrade a Signature Ability by 8 levels.
- Getting a Tier 4 duplicate will upgrade a Signature Ability by 20 levels.
- Getting a Tier 5 duplicate will upgrade a Signature Ability by `TODO` levels.

It can be seen on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4nMzNMhtSA), [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/ContestOfChampions/comments/3mi0w8/99_duped_deadpool/) and [this Wikia page](http://marvel-contestofchampions.wikia.com/wiki/Signature_Ability).